# When simulating RPL Attack in Cooja, modifications made to core files affect normal motes behavior during experiment?

Tags: contiki, cooja, objective-function, rpl

I wanted to seek your help to answer the following question:
I want to implement RPL attack in cooja, so I built the scenario with sink and normal nodes and the run the network.
Afterward, including the attack node requires some modifications to core files such as rpl-private.h, rpl-timers.c, rpl-mrhof.c. As known these files will be used by the normal motes during the simulation run.
The question is modifying these files shall affect normal motes behavior when running the scenario after modifications and adding the malicious mote?
If yes What are the possible solutions?

I have done the normal scenario and trying to figure out how to get my simulations done correctly as i'm measing the impact of RPL rank attack on network topology.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a copy of the `contiki` folder first, rename it to `contiki_attack`, then edit the files in `contiki_attack` folder. You can add motes from the new folder as malicious nodes while you keep using the old `contiki`.